# Problem with F minor 7 guitar chord

Tags: guitar, chords, acoustic-guitar

I am having some problem with an E-shaped F minor 7th barre chord. No matter what I do, it seems impossible to barre 5 strings (and even if I manage somehow to do it, it's very shaky and not clean at all). Any advice what should I do?

Comment: Check out this question : http://music.stackexchange.com/q/1767/7222 . There are also a  lot of other questions addressing this on the site. Most likely either your barreing technique is bad or your fingers aren't strong enough yet as with practice and good technique you should be able to barre all 6 strings on any fret.

Comment: In addition to the above linked question, there are a few other questions specifically about F chords, like http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22486/barre-chord-f-and-barre-chords-in-general?rq=1. I think we can call this a duplicate even though the Fm7 might be the hardest of all the F barre chords, the tips on being able to play it will be the same for all barre chords.

Comment: But I don't really have a problem with the regular F or even Fm. I got them and use them quite often now, without a problem. It's only a Fm7 that bothers me quite a lot. :/

Comment: The edit does nothing to make this question no longer a duplicate. The process you went through to get the major F and Fm chords down is the same process you can use for Fm7.

Answer (score 3):

If you can successfully barre in other fret locations, then your difficulty may be related to the guitar setup -- specifically, the nut may be too high. As a beginner, I would let someone experienced inspect the instrument and offer their opinion.

Note that guitar setup involves a number of interrelated factors.

Comment: I have no problem with F barre or A shaped barres, even on 1st fret. Only this Fm7 and maaybe A shaped m7 and dom 7 Bb. Could this be because of the nut height?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to do an E-shaped Fm7. You could try playing an f minor 7th somewhere else on your neck, e.g.

D-shape

```
4
4
5
3
x
x
```

A-shape

```
8
9
8
10
8
8
```

You could also try adding the 7th on the B string, instead of the D string.

```
1
4
1
3
3
1
```

Comment: Yes, I probably should have mentioned it's E-shape Fm7. I have no problem on other frets, just recently got it pretty stable on 2 fret. But 1 fret seems really hard. But I'd really like to get this regular E-shape Fm7 working.

Comment: @bah if there's a problem on fret 1 that you're not having elsewhere, definitely worth having someone take a look at the nut height.